# make an osx preference panel with section

Tags: objective-c, macos, user-interface, interface-builder

[image]

I need to make a preference panel with section like this.
but what is the exactly compoment has effect like these
(section I means "General,Accounts,RSS...")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SS_PrefsController` by [Matt Legend Gemmell](http://mattgemmell.com/source) looks like it's just what you want.